# JS Calculator - Can't do multiple operations / chain calculations

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm currently creating a vanilla JS Calculator and I have some issues.

Everything is working fine, except I can't do multiple calculations. It can't do multiple operations, it only works if you press the "=" button after each operation. So you can't do it without it. I realized I need to somehow store the result of the operations and then use it for the calculations but don't know how, it doesn't sound hard to fix but can't solve it.

This is the full code, at this stage:

```
const display = document.querySelector(".display");
const numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".number");
const operators = document.querySelectorAll(".operator");

let firstNumber = Number("");
let secondNumber = Number("");
let operator = "";
let lastValue = "";



numbers.forEach((numBtn) => {
  numBtn.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (operator === "") {
      firstNumber += event.target.innerText;
      console.log(parseInt(firstNumber));
      display.textContent = parseInt(firstNumber);
    } else {
      secondNumber += event.target.innerText;
      console.log(parseInt(event.target.innerText));
      display.textContent = Number.parseInt(secondNumber);
    }
  });
});


operators.forEach((opBtn) => {
  opBtn.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (event.target.innerText !== "=") {
      operator = event.target.innerText;
      
    } else {
      switch (operator) {
        case "+":
          lastValue = Number(parseInt(firstNumber) + parseInt(secondNumber));
          firstNumber = lastValue;
          secondNumber = "";
          operator = "";
          display.textContent = lastValue;
          break;


        case "-":
          lastValue = Number(parseInt(firstNumber) - parseInt(secondNumber));
          firstNumber = lastValue;
          secondNumber = "";
          operator = "";
          display.textContent = lastValue;
          break;


        case "*":
          lastValue = Number(parseInt(firstNumber) * parseInt(secondNumber));
          firstNumber = lastValue;
          secondNumber = "";
          operator = "";
          display.textContent = lastValue;
          break;


        case "/":
          lastValue = Number(parseInt(firstNumber) / parseInt(secondNumber)).toFixed(2);
          firstNumber = lastValue;
          secondNumber = "";
          operator = "";
          display.textContent = lastValue;
          break;

          
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  });
});



///
let clearBtn = document.getElementById("AC");

clearBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  firstNumber = "";
  secondNumber = "";
  operator = "";
  display.textContent = "0";
});


///
let resetBtn = document.getElementById("DEL");

resetBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {

  firstNumber = firstNumber.slice(0, -1);

  display.textContent = display.textContent.slice(0, -1);

});
```

I just started the project yesterday and I haven't really progressed with it because I'm really new to programming. I started learning programming a month ago, so please bear with me, haha.

Here is a Codepen link also: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/donatcs/pen/KKXORej)

Answer (score 2):

There was unnecessary complexity, please try this

```js
    const display = document.querySelector(".display");
    const numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".number");
    const operators = document.querySelectorAll(".operator");
    let expression = "";

    numbers.forEach((numBtn) => {
        numBtn.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            expression += event.target.value;
            display.textContent = expression
        });
    });

    operators.forEach((opBtn) => {
        opBtn.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            operator = event.target.innerText;
            switch (operator) {
                case "+":
                case "-":
                case "*":
                case "/":
                    expression += operator;
                    display.textContent = expression;
                    break;
                case "=":
                    display.textContent = eval(expression);
                    break;
                case "AC":
                    expression = ""
                    display.textContent = "0"
                    break;
                case "DEL":
                    display.textContent = display.textContent.slice(0, -1);
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
body {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(173, 143, 173), rgb(32, 86, 129));
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.container {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.363);
  width: 320px; 
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 1.3em;
  box-shadow: -3px -3px 7px #ffffff73,
              2px 2px 5px rgba(94, 104, 121, 0.288);
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 32px 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-shadow: rgba(4, 6, 7, 0.582) 0px 20px 30px -10px;
 
}   


.container .display {
    width: 100%;
    height: 140px;
    width: 320px;
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px #babecc,
                inset -5px -5px 10px #ffffff73;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    
    
  }
  .container .display {
 
    font-size: 37pt;
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;

  }


  .buttons {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns:  70px 70px 70px 70px;
    grid-gap: 0.8em;
    border-radius: 0.35em;
    

  }
  .container .buttons .operator, .container .buttons .number  {
    width: 70px;
    height: 52px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #111;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    top: -20px;
    font-weighT: bold;
}
    

  .container .buttons #equals {

    width: 235px;
  }


.container .buttons .operator:before {
    content: '';
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff0000, #ff7300, #fffb00, #48ff00, #00ffd5, #002bff, #7a00ff, #ff00c8, #ff0000);
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left:-2px;
    background-size: 400%;
    z-index: -1;
    filter: blur(5px);
    width: calc(100% + 4px);
    height: calc(100% + 4px);
    animation: glowing 20s linear infinite;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 10px;
}


.container .buttons .number:before {
  content: '';
  background: linear-gradient(250deg, #4400ff, #ff7300, #fffb00, #48ff00, #00ffd5, #002bff, #7a00ff, #ff00c8, #ff0000);
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left:-2px;
  background-size: 400%;
  z-index: -1;
  filter: blur(5px);
  width: calc(100% + 4px);
  height: calc(100% + 4px);
  animation: glowing 30s linear infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

.container .buttons .operator:active {
    color: #000
}

.container .buttons .operator:active:after {
    background: transparent;
}

.container .buttons .operator:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
}

.container .buttons .operator:after {
    z-index: -1;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #111;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

@keyframes glowing {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    50% { background-position: 400% 0; }
    100% { background-position: 0 0; }
}


.container .buttons .number:active {
    color: #000
}

.container .buttons .number:active:after {
    background: transparent;
}

.container .buttons .number:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
}

.container .buttons .number:after {
    z-index: -1;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #111;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

@keyframes glowing {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    50% { background-position: 400% 0; }
    100% { background-position: 0 0; }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body> 
  <div class="container">   
        <div class="display">0</div>
    <div class="buttons">
       <button class="number" value=0>0</button>
      <button class="number" value=1>1</button>
        <button class="number" value=2>2</button>
        <button class="number" value=3>3</button>
       <button class="number" value=4>4</button>
        <button class="number" value=5>5</button>
        <button class="number" value=6>6</button>
        <button class="number" value=7>7</button>
        <button class="number" value=8>8</button>
        <button class="number" value=9>9</button>
        <button class="operator" id="+" value="+">+</button>
        <button class="operator" id="=" value="=">=</button>
        <button class="operator" id="-" value="-">-</button>
        <button class="operator" id="*" value="*">*</button>
        <button class="operator" id="/" value="/">/</button>
        <button class="operator" id="AC" value="AC">AC</button>
        <button class="operator" id="DEL" value="DEL">DEL</button>

      </div>
      </div>
      
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! But this doesn't really work well, if you test it.

Comment: which feature is not working ?

Comment: The "=" and the multiple operations.

Comment: = is working for me, let me try *

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: * and / uses different logic then + and - that's why it's missing those. my bad

Comment: Will you update your solution?

Comment: it will take time

Comment: Alright, thank you, will wait.

Comment: @opxxx edited the code, added `eval`, but please read through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval